# TweenAnimationBuilder reset animation to the starting point onEnd and start again when an event is triggered

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

Trying to build an Exam app where I'm getting only one question at a time on each hit from API. What I'm trying to do is to build question and start the timer (90-0) when question is displayed. After timer is 0 or submit button is pressed, the new question is build (after getting data from API) and timer starts again from 90 seconds. At the moment, timer goes from 90 to 0 and stops and doesn't start after `setState`

I have seen and tried other solutions like creating a `startTimer()` function but `TweenAnimationBuilder` seems fit for the task. However, couldn't figure out to start it again using `onEnd`.

Here is my TweenAnimationBuilder:

```
          TweenAnimationBuilder(
                tween: Tween(begin: 90.0, end: 0.0),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 90),
                builder: (context, value, child) {
                 num val = value;
                 num time = val.toInt();
                      return Stack(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                              children: [
                                     normalText(
                                           text: "$time",
                                               size: 25,
                                               color: color__orange),
                                               SizedBox(
                                                   width: 60,
                                                   height: 60,
                                                   child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                                              value: time /
                                                                  90,
                                                              valueColor: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(
                                                                  color__orange),
                                                            ),

                                                          ),
                                                        ]
                                                    );
                                                  },
                                                  onEnd: (){
                                                    var questionID = snapshot.data!.quizzesData!.first.questionID;
                                                    QuizQuestion(questionID);
                                                    setState(() {
                                                    });
                                                  },
                                                ),
```

And Here is the Submit Button:

```
           ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: color__orange ),
              onPressed: (){
              if (selectedOptionStatus == 'True') {
              var questionID = snapshot.data!.quizzesData!.first.questionID;
              var score = snapshot.data!.quizzesData!.first.question!.first.marks;
              var answerID = snapshot.data!.quizzesData!.first.question!.first.answer![index].answerID;
                                                    QuizQuestion(questionID);
                                                    StudentQuestionAnswer(questionID, score, answerID);

                                                    // currentQuestionIndex = int.parse(widget.totalQuestions) - remainingQuestions;
                                                    currentQuestionIndex++;

                if ( (currentQuestionIndex + 1) == int.parse(widget.totalQuestions)) {
                                                      updateStudentQuizLoginHistoryFinish();
                                                    }
                                                    setState(() {});
                                                  }
                                                  else {
                                                    if (selectedOptionStatus == 'False') {
                                                      var questionID = snapshot.data!.quizzesData!.first.questionID;
                                                      var score = '0';
                                                      var answerID = snapshot.data!.quizzesData!.first.question!.first.answer![index].answerID;

                                                      QuizQuestion(questionID);
                                                      StudentQuestionAnswer(questionID, score, answerID);
                                                      currentQuestionIndex++;

                                                      if (currentQuestionIndex + 1 == int.parse(widget.totalQuestions)) {
                                                        StudentQuiz();
                                                      }
                                                      setState(() {});
                                                    }
                                                  }

                                                },
                                                child: const Text('Save Answer')
                                            )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide key to TweenAnimationBuilder

`key: ValueKey(questionId)`

This will force the previous TweenAnimationBuilder to be disposed and new one will be created and attached.