# Why I got A RenderFlex overflowed by 8.0 pixels on the right With flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hello everyone I'm trying to display an alert with flutter bu I got this error:  A RenderFlex overflowed by 8.0 pixels on the right.
this is my code:

```dart
return showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
  builder: (context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Flexible(
      child: Row(children: [
        Text(
          '  Alert Dialog Title. $a ',
        ),
        Image.asset(
          'assets/alert.png',
          scale: 1.0,
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
      ]),
    ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent[700],
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
    Radius.circular(20.0),
  ),
  side: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.white,
    width: 3,
  )),
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
);
```

[image: expected result]
NB: the problem occured when I added the picture to the title.

Comment: have you tried decreasing the image size? and can you add a screenshot of the ui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need wrap your Text in `Expanded` and pass your widget in `content` property and remove `Flexible`, like this:

```
showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              content: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '  Alert Dialog Title. asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd  asdasdasdasd',
                        maxLines: 2,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 70,
                    height: 70,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/test.jpeg',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent[700],
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                  side: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: 3,
                  )),
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            );
          },
        );
```

[image]

Comment: can you please have a look on this question. [Link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74543067/tweenanimationbuilder-reset-animation-to-the-starting-point-onend-and-start-agai)

Comment: you can Please tell me how to put the height of the picture the same as the box size

Comment: @rania could you include a ui image of what you want?

Comment: I edited my question . the part where 4.1 is a pic

Comment: @rania I updated my answer, check it out. your text shouldn't be more than 2 lines,

Comment: But still the same prwoblem . I want that the picture take the same height as the alertDialog box

Comment: @rania now I get what you want, check out the updated answer.